# Does using fixtures make a unit test an integration test?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, integration-tests

Does using touching a database mean a unit test is an integration test even if you are using fixtures?

If so, what are the alternatives to write a unit test when you need to use models as a part of a test in a CRUD app (e.g. Ruby on Rails)?

Comment: What sort of "fixtures" would you be referring to?  Fixtures that contain a database?

Comment: **Integration testing** is the phase in software testing in which individual software modules are combined and tested as a group.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_testing

Comment: Does it really matter?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A test fixture is the constraining of the parameters around a set of tests. In other words, setting up mocks, input data etc that will be shared by a number of tests are part of a test fixture.

People endlessly debate what’s a unit test and what’s an integration test. For me, the only useful definition I’ve come across is that, if a test can be isolated (ie it has no side effects and can be run in parallel), then it’s a unit test. Everything else is an integration test. Others might disagree with this, eg by viewing testing a method in isolation as a unit test and everything else as integration tests.

Regardless of which definitions you favour, it’s clear that the terms are unrelated to test fixtures. So no, using a fixture does not transform a unit test into an integration test.

Comment: This **if a test can be isolate (ie it has no side effects and can be run in parallel), then it’s a unit test** should be bolded

Comment: And I will add: _unit tests should be fast_.

Comment: And I will improve: *all tests should be fast*

Comment: @Mariyo, all tests should be as fast as possible. But sometimes that may not fit into normal definitions of "fast". Overnight test runs of hours can still be of benefit for example as finding a bug overnight is better than finding it in production, weeks later.